# Validação caracteres restantes

Tags: javascript

Crie a função JavaScript chamada “contaCaracteresRestantes(idCampoTexto, idSpan)” que conte quantos caracteres restam no campo “txtVoce” e mostre esta quantidade de caracteres restantes no span“carResTxtVoce”. Define-se o campo no código HTML como tendo 40 colunas e 10 linhas, ou seja, 400 caracteres. Dica: a função deve ser chamada no evento onChange do campo “txtVoce”. Dica 2: os argumentos de entrada idCampo e idSpan devem ser os id’s do campo “txtVoce” e do span “carResTxtVoce”.

Por favor já tentei, mas não consigo resolver essa questão, podem me ajudar?

```html
<div><label for="txtVoce">Faleme sobre você:</label></div>
            <div><textarea id="txtVoce" maxlength="100" name="txtVoce" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
            <p><span id="carResTxtVoce" style="font-weight: bold;">400</span> caracteres restantes</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
function contaCaracteresRestantes(idCampoTexto, idSpan) {
  var n = document.getElementById(idCampoTexto).value.length;
  document.getElementById(idSpan).innerHTML = 400 - n;
}
```

```html
<div><label for="txtVoce">Faleme sobre você:</label></div>
<div><textarea id="txtVoce" maxlength="100" name="txtVoce" cols="40" rows="10" onKeyUp="contaCaracteresRestantes('txtVoce', 'carResTxtVoce')"></textarea>
<p><span id="carResTxtVoce" style="font-weight: bold;">400</span> caracteres restantes</p>
```

Se quiser que o contador atualize enquanto digita (como no exemplo acima), use `onKeyUp` e/ou `onKeyDown` ao invés de `onChange`, que foi sugerido no enunciado. Caso use `onChange`, você terá que clicar fora do `textarea` para o contador atualizar.